# Counting names in same cell

Tags: count, cell, names

in Excel 365, I have a column (F5:F43) were each cell has a number of names in it, some the same name i.e.John, Fred, Sue, John, Fred, on another row (Q5:Q34) I have a list of the names that appear in column F, what formula should I use to count the total number of times each name (Q5:Q34) appears, the total should count both entries in the same cell

Tried
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Q5, $F$5:$F$43)))
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(F5:F43, Q5))
an count, countif, countifs.
they count but only count the first name not the second in the same cell.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.